# printing links with smarty php

Tags: php, css, smarty

this code block is printing links to a div but the first link prints in the correct location and the rest print outside of the div. any ideas why?

```
{if count($from)}
<div class="classifieds">
<div class="pop">
<ul>
{foreach from=$from item=item key=key name=tmp}
  <li>
    <div class="title"><a href="{$item.link}">{$item.title}</a></div>
  </li>
   {if $item.featured}</div>{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
</div>
 </div>
{else}
<div class="centerText">{$language.nothing_found}</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Show your Output html. which div you are closing here {if $item.featured}</div>{/if}

Comment: Show the output like @Manwal said, check where something weirds happens/shows. Look at that lines in the code.

Comment: Thanks guys these are amazing ideas of how to solve this. Good thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i could understand this correctly

```
{if count($from)}
<div class="classifieds">
<div class="pop">
<ul>
{foreach from=$from item=item key=key name=tmp}
  <li>
    <div class="title"><a href="{$item.link}">{$item.title}</a></div>
  </li>
   {if $item.featured}</div>{/if}//remove this line
{/foreach}
</ul>
</div>
 </div>
{else}
<div class="centerText">{$language.nothing_found}</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: NICE THANK YOU!!!!!!!
What was that line saying? This smarty thing is confusing me...